# What will happen to transcription if histone acetyltransferases are removed from a eukaryotic cell?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology

If HATs are destroyed in a eukaryotic cell, how will gene expression level be affected? Will all gene expression be affected or just be slowed down and most gene will still be expressed?

Comment: There are many HATs, but I would expect many of them to be lethal knockouts, for example [this](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/interpro/entry/IPR005910).

Comment: Yes as March Ho said there are several HATs. Hat1 knockout is lethal [[Ref](http://journals.plos.org/plosgenetics/article?id=10.1371/journal.pgen.1003518)]